# How to get the date format based on locale using Intl.DateTimeFormat in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization

I want to get the standard date format (like MM/DD/YYYY) of the date based on given local id. But below code is not giving the format. Please help how I can get the date format.

```
var dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("as-IN").
```

Comment: There is no native API for that but you can infer parts of it from `Intl`. Do you need the date only? Does it matter whether it is "M/D/YY" or "MM/DD/YYYY"?

Comment: I want, whatever standard date format is there for local id

Comment: There is no universal formatting specification. For example "D" does not mean the same thing for Moment.js and date-fns. Thus you would have to detect the format for your actual use case. You can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat#formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) as starting point.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was to first format a dummy date based on the locale. Then I would replace distinct date parts (day, month, year) with the standard placeholders `DD`, `MM`, `YYYY`.

This is the code:

```js
/**
 * Returns date format used by Intl.DateTimeFormat (for specified `options`).
 * Example for Serbia: `DD/MM/YYYY`
 *
 * **Note** that this will always return the two decimal format for day and month and four for year (e.g. `DD/MM/YYYY`)
 */
export function getIntlDateFormatForLocale(locale: string, options?: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions) {
  const year = 2222
  const month = 12
  const day = 15
  const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day)
  const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, options).format(date)
  return formattedDate.replace(`${year}`, 'YYYY').replace(`${month}`, 'MM').replace(`${day}`, 'DD')
}
```

**Please note that** the format you get out of this is for two-digit representation of date parts. This means that if the user has a single-digit locale set up, using this format will yield two-digit date parts.

E.g.: If a user locale outputs dates like `1/1/2021`, it will be formatted as `01/01/2021` when using the format from this function.

It will also not work correctly when format outputs weekdays (e.g. `Mon`), Mandarin/Japanese/Arabic digits, etc.

There might be some other caveats, but for my use-case, this was good enough ;)

Comment: This needs to be downvoted into the negatives.

Comment: I know it is hackish  That's why there are so many "disclaimers". @mellis481 Feel free to provide your own solution or edit mine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73496711/1048572 has a nicer (but still hacky) approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic loop returns remote sense locale:

```
        let longDateFormat ='';
        for(let i=0;i<new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts().length;i++){
            if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "year") {
                longDateFormat += "yyyy";
            } else if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "literal"){
                longDateFormat += new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].value;
            } else if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "day") {
                longDateFormat += "dd";
            } else if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "month") {
                longDateFormat += "MM";
            }
        }
        console.log(longDateFormat);
```