# Get string format for date based on locale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to get the format string for dates like "dd/MM/yyyy" based on locale. I want to use it in a picker date component to change the default format based on language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Locale Short Date Format using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388115/get-locale-short-date-format-using-javascript)

Comment: See also [How to determine users locale date format using javascript (format is dd/mm or mm/dd)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43368659/215552), [Locale and specific date format with Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27360102/215552), [Get the format of time for any country](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70017566/215552), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but I would like others if is possible.

```
function getDateFormatPattern(locale: string) {
    const getPatternForPart = (part: Intl.DateTimeFormatPart) => {
        switch (part.type) {
            case 'day':
                return 'd'.repeat(part.value.length);
            case 'month':
                return 'M'.repeat(part.value.length);
            case 'year':
                return 'y'.repeat(part.value.length);
            case 'literal':
                return part.value;
        }
    };

    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).formatToParts(new Date('2022-01-01'))
        .map(getPatternForPart)
        .join('');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic loop returns remote sense locale:

```
            let dd ='';
            for(let i=0;i<new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts().length;i++){
                if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "year") {
                    dd += "yyyy";
                } else if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "literal"){
                    dd += new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].value;
                } else if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "day") {
                    dd += "dd";
                } else if(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).formatToParts()[i].type === "month") {
                    dd += "MM";
                }
            }
            console.log(dd);
```